# Hashcode are always the same?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if HashCode are always the same.?

For instance:

```
String myString = "my super string";
Int myHashCode = myString.GetHashCode();
```

Will `myHashCode` always be the same value? On any computer, at anytime, on any everything?

Can I trust in this in value to use it as a custom unique identity ( for the same object type)

Comment: Do you understand what a hash code *is*?

Comment: Yes. I know what they are used for. What I dont understand is how it is generated. I need to create a custom Int64 Id in a class used to chain messages. Looks like I am going to use an incremental identity in Sql server...

Answer (score 7):

No, the value can change between computers and base system versions.

You should only depend on it to be constant during a given program run.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value returned by GetHashCode is platform-dependent. It differs on the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the .NET Framework. It also can differ between versions of the .NET Framework.
>
> **Caution:** A hash code is intended for efficient insertion and lookup in collections that are based on a hash table. A hash code is not a permanent value. For this reason:
>
> - Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases.

---

> Can I trust in this in value to use it as a custom unique identity?

That won't work either, even during a single program run, as hash codes do collide (same hash code for *unequal* objects).

To quote the docs again:

> - Do not test for equality of hash codes to determine whether two objects are equal. (Unequal objects can have identical hash codes.) To test for equality, call the ReferenceEquals or Equals method.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation:

If two string objects are equal, the GetHashCode method returns identical values. However, there is not a unique hash code value for each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash code.
The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain.
As a result, hash codes should never be used outside of the application domain in which they were created, they should never be used as key fields in a collection, and they should never be persisted.

Hash code is derived from the value for string and for other objects it is derived from the memory location.

It can produce same hashcode for different strings, as collisions may occur, so as a thumb rule never use hashcode as a key as they change,here is a good source about hashcode:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/

Comment: How does that answer the questions?

Comment: I think i answers the question just fine.

"Will myHashCode always be the same value?  On any computer, at anytime, on any everything?" => May differ across platforms, app domains, .Net framework etc.